# Can't see child when appending element to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to append a child to my HTML document, and I can see it in the source code, although it doesn't pop-up on the screen which I found weird.

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="myForm">
      <select name="type" id="selectedoption">
          <option value="">Välj typ här</option>
          <option value="photo">Foto</option>
          <option value="video">Video</option>
          <option value="audio">Ljud</option>  
      </select>
      <input type="text" name="title"> Titel
      <input type="submit" value="Spara media" class="btn">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
<script src="test.js"> </script>
```

This is my JS:

```
var iDiv = document.createElement('input');
iDiv.type = 'file';
iDiv.name = 'media';
iDiv.accept = 'image/*';
document.getElementById("selectedoption").appendChild(iDiv);
```

And here's a snippet:

```js
var iDiv = document.createElement('input');
iDiv.type = 'file';
iDiv.name = 'media';
iDiv.accept = 'image/*';
document.getElementById("selectedoption").appendChild(iDiv);
```

```html
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="myForm">
  <select name="type" id="selectedoption">
    <option value="">Välj typ här</option>
    <option value="photo">Foto</option>
    <option value="video">Video</option>
    <option value="audio">Ljud</option>  
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="title"> Titel
  <input type="submit" value="Spara media" class="btn">
</form>
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here..?

Comment: When does this code execute?

Comment: You can't append an `input` to a `<select>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't append an `input` to a `select`. A select element should only contain `option` or `optgroup` tags.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="myForm">
      <select name="type" id="selectedoption">
          <option value="">Välj typ här</option>
          <option value="photo">Foto</option>
          <option value="video">Video</option>
          <option value="audio">Ljud</option>  
      </select>
      <input type="text" name="title"> Titel
      <input type="submit" value="Spara media" class="btn">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
<script>
var iDiv = document.createElement('option');
iDiv.value = 'file';
iDiv.textContent = "File";
document.getElementById("selectedoption").appendChild(iDiv);
</script>
```

If you want to append a file input to your form, you should use the `appendChild` method on the form.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="myForm">
      <select name="type" id="selectedoption">
          <option value="">Välj typ här</option>
          <option value="photo">Foto</option>
          <option value="video">Video</option>
          <option value="audio">Ljud</option>  
      </select>
      <input type="text" name="title"> Titel
      <input type="submit" value="Spara media" class="btn">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
<script>
var iDiv = document.createElement('input');
iDiv.type = 'file';
iDiv.name = 'media';
iDiv.accept = 'image/*';
document.querySelector('form').appendChild(iDiv);
</script>
```

Comment: Great, that helped :) Thanks

Comment: @tryingsohard No problem.